# Where can I download ffmpeg with libfaac?

Tags: windows, ffmpeg

Where can I download ffmpeg with libfaac (for Windows)?

Answer (score 6):

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp3 -c:a aac -strict 2 out.aac
```

or simply

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp3 out.aac
```

Answer (score 2):

looks like you have to compile your own, the "official" binary distros probably don't have it because of "licensing collisions" (typically that x264 is GPL and libfaac's license isn't GPL friendly but you can build it yourself).

so you can build it yourself with it: http://pcloadletter.co.uk/2011/05/07/compiling-64bit-ffmpeg-for-windows-with-libfaac http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/forum/mcp.php?i=main&mode=topic_view&f=19&t=459&sid=3b427270937ecfcd8f2e57a34a5213e2

or use a sherpya ffmpeg and have the .dll in your path: http://oss.netfarm.it/mplayer-win32.php

See also [FFmpeg command to convert MP3 to AAC](https://superuser.com/questions/370625/ffmpeg-command-to-convert-mp3-to-aac) where it mentions that you can now use -acodec libvo_aacenc by default.