# FFmpeg command to convert MP3 to AAC

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, mp3, aac, audio-conversion

I can issue this command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -acodec alac -ab 128k -ar 48000 -ac 2 -y output.m4a
```

to create a m4a file.

But when I issue this command

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -acodec alac -ab 128k -ar 48000 -ac 2 -y output.aac
```

ffmpeg is throwing an error saying

> Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?).

Also, the size of the m4a file is really almost 5.8 times larger than the original file, which is absolutely not what I wanted and why I wanted to convert to AAC.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

#### How can I convert to AAC?

This is the most basic FFmpeg command to convert input to AAC audio using the highest quality AAC FFmpeg has. `libfdk_aac` is the Fraunhofer AAC encoder, and it is available when you compiled FFmpeg with support for it.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -c:a libfdk_aac output.m4a
```

To change the quality, you have two options:

- For variable bitrate (VBR), use the `-vbr` option. For example, `-vbr 4` is a good choice (roughly 128 kBit/s for stereo audio). Higher means better. Values range from 1 to 5.

  ```
  ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -c:a libfdk_aac -vbr 4 output.m4a
  ```
- For fixed bitrate (CBR), use the `-b:a` option, for example `-b:a 128k`. 128 kBit/s should be good enough for most situations. You can often choose something lower as well.

  ```
  ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 128k output.m4a
  ```

You can also use HE-AAC (v1/v2) instead of the default AAC-LC (low complexity) profile, which is best suited for low bitrates:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -c:a libfdk_aac -profile:a aac_he_v2 -b:a 32k output.m4a
```

---

#### What if I don't have `libfdk_aac`?

Some versions of FFmpeg do not have `libfdk_aac` (for licensing reasons). If that's the case, you can use the built-in AAC encoder:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -c:a aac -b:a 192k output.m4a
```

This encoder does not support VBR properly, so if you need that or HE-AAC, read on.

You can compile ffmpeg yourself and add `libfdk_aac` support. There are guides [on the FFmpeg Wiki](https://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/CompilationGuide). Compiling is easy on Linux, moderately easy on OS X, and rather hard on Windows. When you follow the compilation guides and install the appropriate libraries before, FFmpeg now gives you the option to use `libfdk_aac`.

---

There were some problems with your original approach:

- `alac` is not AAC. ALAC is the [Apple Lossless Audio Codec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alac), whereas AAC is [Advanced Audio Coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aac).
- That's why your output is larger than the input, because in contrast to MP3, ALAC is still compressed, but it needs to be lossless – that's why it needs to store more data.
- `.aac` is not an output container for ALAC audio. If you use AAC, that should work. I would use MP4 or M4A though.

Comment: On Ubuntu 12.04 I was unable to use an option `-c:a`, does this have any synonym?  I guess it might mean `-acodec:a` but in the end I just dropped it, and `ffmpeg` was able to deduce a codec based on the desired output file name. (Need `-strict experimental` though; and threw in `-map_metadata 0:0` for good measure, to preserve ID3 tags.)

Comment: Also worth noting: I wanted M4B files (audiobooks), which `ffmpeg` does not appear to support, but converting into M4A and then just renaming seems to work.

Comment: @tripleee That means you're using an outdated program called `ffmpeg`, but it's really not from FFmpeg, but the Libav fork. Ubuntu unfortunately bundled it instead of the "real" ffmpeg. See: [Who can tell me the difference and relation between ffmpeg, libav, and avconv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477115/who-can-tell-me-the-difference-and-relation-between-ffmpeg-libav-and-avconv)

Comment: @slhck: Thanks for the quick update and the link!

Comment: @tripleee Actually no, .m4a files are identical to .mp4 (it's just a convention naming for mp4 files with audio only), but have a different format than .aac (which is known as an ADTS stream). You can also force FFmpeg to output in ADTS format by adding `-f adts`.

Comment: If you're getting errors starting "Could not find tag for codec" then this is probably because ffmpeg is trying (and failing) to convert the album art to aac. I worked around this with `-vn` but that will mean the resulting aac files won't have album art.

Answer (score 6):

**Easy convert to AAC for Zeranoe Windows Builds**

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -c:a aac -b:a 128k output.m4a
```

Use "aac" instead of libfaac or libfdk_aac:
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC

*"FFmpeg can support three AAC-LC encoders (aac, libfaac, libfdk_aac) and one HE-AAC(v1/2) encoder (libfdk_aac). The licenses of libfaac and libfdk_aac are not compatible with the GPL, so the GPL does not permit distribution of binaries containing code licensed under these licenses when GPL-licensed code is also included."*

Comment: `libfaac` support has also been removed as of 3.2.