# Converting video to WebM with ffmpeg/avconv

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, webm

While [trying to optimize the size of my home videos](https://superuser.com/questions/556452/in-which-format-to-store-home-made-videos-converting-to-webm-using-cli) I converted some of them to WebM as a test, using Pitivi on Xubuntu. The size difference is significant. The resulting webm-file is only around 10% of the original file, while the picture quality looks pretty much the same to me.

I also tried to do the conversion using `avconv` so I could script it, but the resulting file looks really crappy. After looking at the rendering settings in Pitivi I tried some parameters: `avconv -i $1 -q 5 -qmin 0 -qmax 63  ${1%.*}.webm`, but the quality still looks like crap, so it seems I'm missing/using some wrong paramters. Does somebody know which are the correct parameters to use to convert a h264 movie to a webm and get the same quality as from Pitivi?

These are the settings in Pitivi:
[image: creating the Pitivi Project]
[image: Rendering to webm (html5 video)]
[image: codec configuration]

Answer (score 55, accepted):

> **Note:** This information is based on the FFmpeg Wiki on [VP9 encoding](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/VP9). Please refer to that article for more information – it will be continuously maintained and extended. For the best results you should use the a recent version of `ffmpeg` by [downloading it from their website](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) (a static build will suffice; it contains the `libvps-vp9` encoder).

### Variable Bit Rate

VBR encoding gives you the optimal overall quality, since the encoder can freely choose how many bits to assign to a frame. Choose this mode unless you are preparing videos for constant-bitrate streaming.

#### Option 1: Constant quality encoding

Typically, if you do not want to target a specific file size, you should let the bitrate vary freely, as that will lead to the highest quality. You can do this by setting the bitrate to 0 and the constant rate factor ([CRF](http://slhck.info/video/2017/02/24/crf-guide.html)) to the target quality level:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libvpx-vp9 -crf 30 -b:v 0 output.webm
```

CRF value can be from 0–63. Lower values mean better quality. Recommended values range from 15–35, with 31 being recommended for 1080p HD video. Google has a guide with [more info on that](https://developers.google.com/media/vp9/settings/vod/).

#### Option 2: Two-pass encoding with a target bitrate

If you want your file to have a specific target bitrate or file size, you need to specify the rate and use two-pass encoding (which will ensure an optimal quality distribution). Here we're choosing 5 MBit/s, which should be enough for 1080p content.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libvpx-vp9 -b:v 5M -pass 1 -f webm /dev/null && \
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libvpx-vp9 -b:v 5M -pass 2 output.webm
```

Windows users need to use `NUL` instead of `/dev/null`, and a `^` instead of `\`.

### Constant Bit Rate

First of all, libvpx [offers constant bitrate and variable bitrate encoding modes](http://www.webmproject.org/docs/encoder-parameters/#3-rate-control). Constant bitrate should be avoided whenever possible (unless you target a specific file size or streaming scenario), since the average quality per file size will be worse. Still, you could try setting a constant bitrate if nothing else works for you, e.g. with 1 MBit/s:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libvpx-vp9 -minrate 5M -maxrate 5M -b:v 5M output.webm
```

Look at the output and increase or decrease the bit rate to your liking (or file size constraints). For example, you can use `500K` or `5M`, et cetera.

You have to specify `-minrate`, `-maxrate` and the bitrate `-b:v` in order for the encoder to use CBR. They all have to have the same value—otherwise it'll choose a different target bitrate instead and do VBR encoding, but with bad quality.

### Audio

The current audio codec of choice for VP9 encoding is Opus. FFmpeg will choose the necessary encoder and its options by default. If you want to explicitly set `-c:a libopus`, you can do that as well. Refer to the [`libopus` documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html#libopus-1) for more options.

Comment: This is, currently, the single best guide to encoding VP8 on the whole internet. Well done, I wish I could upvote more that once!

Comment: @evilsoup Thank you. I'm still tweaking it and will add a new page on  the FFmpeg wiki later.

Comment: This is truly a wonderful answer! I now understand why my video was always in the same low quality, because I was actually always using the default of 256 kBit/s. Thank you very much!

Comment: What were the size differentials between the original mp4 and the converted webm?

Comment: @Dan I just updated the guide – noticed that it was a little outdated. Glad you found it useful.