# Use FFMPEG to combine MP4 and MP3 file?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, mp3, video-conversion

I have two files, video.mp4 and genaudio.mp3 (both same length). How can I merge the MP3 file with the MP4 using FFMPEG (or any command line program)?

This is what I have so far, but it doesn't replace the audio after spitting it out:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i genaudio.mp3 -c:v copy -c:a mp3 output.mp4 -y
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You'll have to map the input streams:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i genaudio.mp3 -map 0:v -map 1:a -c:v copy -c:a copy output.mp4 -y
```

When the inputs have multiple streams of a type among them, ffmpeg picks the 'best' one. For audio, that's the one with most number of channels. If those are the same, then it picks a stream from the earliest input.

(No need to re-encode the audio, so I've switched to copy)

Comment: I would totally re encode the mp3 file with an AAC codec [See this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/370625/ffmpeg-command-to-convert-mp3-to-aac), otherwise some players won't read the sound of your video.

Comment: What does the `-y` option do?

Comment: If the output file already exists, ffmpeg will prompt the user to check if it should be overwritten. `-y` forces the overwrite. `-n` forces exit and existing file is left untouched.

Comment: @Gyan what if my input is ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i genaudio.mp3 -i image.png , how do i copy ? beacuse while copying with "-map 0:v -map 1:a -c:v copy -c:a copy output.mp4 -y" image does not appear